# XSS - How to remove broken HTMLs from user(<intput type="text" onclick="alert('12')") from user input

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsoup, xss

Currently I'm using Jsoup for cleaning the user input. But using this I cannot remove the broken HTMLs tags like the one below

```
<intput type="text" onclick="alert('12')"
```

So when this value is rendered in the browser JS is getting executed.

HTML Doctype used:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: Well that text seems to have displayed on _this_ page without any JS executing, so...

Comment: Please provide sample code